# SocketChannel is not ready

Tags: java, android, sockets, nio

again i have got a problem with socket programming in Android. My Problem is Selector.select() returns zero that there are no SocketChannels ready for writing. And again the same code works in normal Java but does not work in Android. Here is my code:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class WebSocketTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

  SocketChannel channel = null;

        SocketAddress socketAdress = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.1", 8787);

  try {
   channel = SocketChannel.open();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("ERROR", "channel open");
  }

  try {
   channel.configureBlocking(false);
  } catch (IOException e1) {
   Log.e("ERROR", "channel blocking");
  }

  try {
   channel.connect(socketAdress);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("ERROR", "channel connect");
  }

  try {
   while(!channel.finishConnect())
   {

   }
  } catch (IOException e1) {
   Log.e("ERROR", "channel finishConnect");
  }


  Selector selector = null;
  try {
   selector = Selector.open();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("ERROR", "selector open");
  }
  try {
   channel.register(selector, channel.validOps());
  } catch (ClosedChannelException e) {
   Log.e("ERROR", "channel register");
  }

  boolean i = true;

  while(i)
  {
   int readyChannels = 0;
   try {
    readyChannels = selector.select();
   } catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("ERROR", "selector select");
   }

   if(readyChannels > 0)
   {
    i = false;
   }
  }
    }
}
```

In Java readyChannels = 1. In Android it is 0.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have this problem on both emulator and devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulator sits behind a virtual router. You need to configure [Network Redirections](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#redirections) (port forwarding) to make a certain port on emulator visible to the outside network (including your computer).

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It turned out to work on the device but not using the emulator.
Of course it would be nice to test it in the emulator. Could you explain to me how to do these Network Redirections?

Comment: It's all described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#console
1. Start emulator 2. Connect to emulator via telnet 3. Execute `redir add tcp:5000:6000` 4. Run your socket software on emulator on port 6000 5. Connect to port 5000 on your local PC and port will be redirected to emulator

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this NIO code.

1. Instead of connecting and then spinning around `finishConnect()`, possibly forever, you should connect before going into non-blocking mode. At the moment you're just burning the CPU, flattening the battery, etc.
2. You should only register `OP_WRITE` when you have something to write. It is normally 'ready', so if you register the channel for it permanently your selection loop will just spin. The only time `OP_WRITE` isn't ready is when you have filled the socket send buffer.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. This helps but does not solve the problem. There are still no Sockets ready.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Android then, but you only need OP_WRITE to be ready if you have previously filled the socket send buffer, i.e. a prior write() has returned zero. If you haven't encountered this condition yet you don't have a problem yet. Just write().